# Why does adding removing an index in the for loop condition cause an error in the nested if statement?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to loop through an array set to outputArray in Google Sheets App Script.

```
outputArray = [[Output 1], [Output 2], ... [Output 100]]
```

I have an if statement nested in this for loop so that if the value contains a certain string, then another for loop will trigger.

Basically it goes, for loop to if statement to for loop (when the if statement is true).

The if statement returns a TypeError: Cannot call method "match" of undefined. I'm not sure why this is happening.

I mistakenly had the first for loop condition set to index [0] which would return 1, so the for loop would only run once. However, having this index [0] would fix the function and it would run through once, and not produce an error in the if statement as explained above.

```
for (var i = 0; i < outputArray.length; i++) {                  

if (outputArray[0][i].match("Output")!=null) {                  

  for (var k = 0; k < getParamValue[0].length; k++) {          
    var param = getParamValue[0][k];
    var paramInLoop = "[[" + String(k + 1) + "]]";
    repTemplate = repTemplate.replace(paramInLoop,param);
  }
}
```

Comment: You're iterating the first array instead of the second array in your for loop condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

- Index`[0]` refers to the first element in the outer array(i.e., the first inner array). Index `[0][i]` iterates the first inner array. But the first inner  array only contains one element. Second element in the first inner array is `undefined` and  `undefined` doesn't have a `match` method and thus it cannot be called.

#### Solution:

- Iterate the outer array first and then the inner array: `[i][0]`

#### Snippet:

```
for (var i = 0; i < outputArray.length; i++) {                  
if (outputArray[i][0].match("Output")!=null) {
```

```js
var outputArray = [['Output 1'], ['Output 2'], ['Output 3']];
for (var i = 0; i < outputArray.length; i++) {               
  console.info('outputArray[0]['+i+'] is'+ outputArray[0][i]);
  console.info('outputArray['+i+'][0] is'+ outputArray[i][0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a hot mess, but I assume this is the solution.

```
for (var i = 0; i < outputArray[0].length; i++) {                  

if (outputArray[0][i].match("Output")!=null) {                  

  for (var k = 0; k < getParamValue[0].length; k++) {          
    var param = getParamValue[0][k];
    var paramInLoop = "[[" + String(k + 1) + "]]";
    repTemplate = repTemplate.replace(paramInLoop,param);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ha yes I am pretty new so I'm sure the code is terrible. Yes adding the index 0 does fix the error, but then the for loop only runs once since outputArray[0].length == 1. I would like it to run through index 0-99 for that array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple function that fills the first 25 rows and 25 columns with a string that identifies each cells row, column.

```
function runOne() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var vA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<25;i++) {
    vA[i]=[];
    for(var j=0;j<25;j++) {
      vA[i][j]=Number(i+1) + ', ' + Number(j+1);
    }
  }
  sh.getRange(1,1,vA.length,vA[0].length).setValues(vA);
}
```

I thought this might help you to understand arrays a little better.